# aws lambda docker fork/exec permission denied

Tags: docker

I am trying to use AWS lambda with docker container. The container is built starting from ubuntu:latest

When running test with AWS lambda console, I get following error:

> Launch error: fork/exec /root/miniconda3/bin/python: permission denied
> Entrypoint: [/root/miniconda3/bin/python,-m,awslambdaric]

The /root/miniconda3/bin/python and awslambdaric files do have correct permission.

Any idea what could be reason?

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into a similar issue where /root had drwxr-x--- permissions (i.e. "others" could not read or execute). When this runs under Lambda, it doesn't run as root so it cannot access directories that are not readable/executable by "other".

When I added "RUN chmod o+rx /root" to my Dockerfile, my lambda ran successfully.

BTW, also check that /root/miniconda3/bin/python is not a symbolic link. I read somewhere that that could also cause this error.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `RUN chmod 777 /root` in Dockerfile worked for me .

Comment: Setting 777 to /root is dangerous, permissions exist for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem running a Python application in a Docker image in AWS Lambda.

The Python files were copied into the root directory, and it had no access when Lambda tried to access them.

The solution was to use `WORKDIR /project` in the Dockerfile to copy all the content into a folder everyone can access. Then, when I trigger the Lambda, I have all the necessary accesses.